# Have US universities seen a significant increase in administrative workforces relative to academic activity?

Tags: united-states, administration, non-academic-staff

I was recently made aware of a [study](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/higher-ed-administrators-growth_n_4738584) (caveat: from 2014) indicating that, supposedly, US academic institutions have taken on non-academic staff at a much higher overall rate than the increase in the student population, counting from 1987 and unti 2011-2012.

Now, the think-tank which authored this study seems fishy to me, but I don't live and work in the US, so I wanted to ask for corroboration or refutation of its claims based on your experience and knowledge.

Note: Academic activity and number of students is not the same thing; information relative either to the former or the latter is relevant.

Comment: I'm wondering why you think a [non-partisan, large thinktank is fishy?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Institutes_for_Research)

Comment: Nearly every university makes public the number of its faculty and administrative staff members as part of the [Common Data Set](https://commondataset.org/); you can certainly check any sample that you feel would be representative. Whether any particular ratio is "overly large" is opinion-based.

Comment: I’m totally sure that audit and reporting burdens have fallen dramatically over the last 33 years.

Comment: Not really sure being from 2014 is that much of a caveat

Comment: @PeterK.: 1. Think tanks typically serve the interests of their funders. I don't know who funds this one so I'm suspicious - especially if it's large 2. If its prominent clients include the US foreign-meddling agency USAID and large for-profit corporations, I'm suspicious 2. Both large US political parties actively favor the interests of large capitalists (individuals and corporations) over other social interests - in a "non-partisan" fashion.

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim: Well, I'm asking this question in 2020.

Comment: Define "overly large". I'm pretty sure that such staff has increased, but so have services as well as governmental regulations. What to one person is _overly large_ is, to another, _just right_. In many places, also, some services to professors have declined. There is less secretarial help available, and professors now type all their own work, rather than having it done. My doctoral dissertation was typed by a secretary skilled in math typing. I paid for it, of course.

Comment: @Buffy: See edit.

Comment: https://www.thirdway.org/report/how-higher-education-data-reporting-is-both-burdensome-and-inadequate Might be enlightening